# JasperReports Server: Scheduled Export of Excel different than manual export

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a JR report being run on a *JR Server*.  I have it set up to export with `isIgnorePagination="true"` and `OnePagePerSheet="true"`.  This works as expected when I manually run the report and choose export both from the *JR Server* web interface and the *iReport* interface but if I schedule the report to run automatically, the exported spreadsheet has many pages instead of the 7 I am expecting.  Basically, it's ignoring the ***isIgnorePagination*** setting when scheduled but not when run manually.  What is the difference?

Comment: How did you set ***isIgnorePagination*** and ***OnePagePerSheet*** parameters?

Comment: I've set isIgnorePagination both through editing the jrxml and through the iReport UI (which does the same thing).  I've set OnePagePerSheet in the jrxml, through the iReport UI and through the ApplicationContext.xml server settings.